# How to change image URL to image itself in Wordpress PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

How to make the Wordpress work like this that when i paste URL of a image to the blog post after publishing it will be replaced automatically with the image itself? I know there is the option to embed the image from the upload image window but i need to have a solution that works like i wrote. Wordpress is in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The risk with this approach is that you will be loading the exact size of the image you link. And if you plan to resize the image in by using `<img src='/path/image1.jpeg' width='..' height='...'/>`, you'll still be loading the original image.

My idea is, you will add a filter for your the_content in your function to search for pattern of the pasted image using regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write your own plugin which implements a filter which matches against the type of content_save_pre.

The filter will need to execute a regular expression to search for http(s) followed by a wildcard and end in .jpg .jpeg .gif .png .tiff etc.

You will then need to loop through all the matches in the content, and then download and add them to your media library. The final step would then be to replace the original URLs in the content with  html tags.